# How to include 2 columns under one column header in html table?

Tags: html, asp.net, html-table

I want to create an html table, which should look like this:

[image]

I know I will have to use colspan/rowspan attributes, but how? Can anyone help?

I have tried following :

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Evaluation</th><th>Approval</th>
<th colspan="2" >Points</th>
<th>Total</th>
<th>Date</th><th>Award Amount</th><th>Last Modified By</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

but is is giving me result as:

[image]

Clearly, I need to subheader in 3rd header (Points), how to achieve this?

Comment: Please show your attempt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is the table fullstructure

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

thanks...

Comment: How is this the accepted answer? There's literally no answer here.

Comment: <table >
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">
                    </td>
                <td rowspan="2">
                    </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    </td>
                <td rowspan="2">
                    </td>
                <td rowspan="2">
                    </td>
                    <td rowspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    </td>
                <td>
                    </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

Answer (score 30):

Like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Evaluation</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Approval</th>
            <th colspan="2">Points</th> // <- note colspan here
            <th rowspan="2">Total</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Date</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Award Amount</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Last Modified By</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Tangible</th>
            <th>Intangible</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Al/GL</td>
            <td>Select</td>
            <td>col1</td>
            <td>col2</td>
            <td>col3</td>
            <td>col4</td>
            <td>col5</td>
            <td>col6</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Great answer! take note of the third column "colspan" rather than "rowspan". I was confused about why this works at first.